# Androguard: 'NameError: name 'AnalyzeAPK' is not defined' error

Tags: python, android, malware-detection, androguard

I am trying to use androguard to analyze a malware apk file but am facing the following error.

> In [1]: a,d,dx = AnalyzeAPK("malware.apk", decompiler="dad")
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/androguard/cli/main.py in  1 a,d,dx = AnalyzeAPK("malware.apk", decompiler="dad")
>
> NameError: name 'AnalyzeAPK' is not defined

I have tried re installing androguard but no change. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You can import `AnalyzeAPK` by running:

```
from androguard.misc import AnalyzeAPK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update to the latest version of androguard. Also, it might be helpful to include the absolute path to the .apk file